# SQL Server data import after modifying tables

Tags: sql-server, data-import

I have a database backup which I imported into SQL Server and made few changes by adding some columns. Did not remove any of the existing columns but added some extra.

Now I wish to import the same database once again so I have all the latest data which was being entered in old one while I was working on adding columns.

What would be the proper, effective and efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restore the Backup on the same server, then run this:

```
INSERT INTO Production.dbo.table1 ( column1, column2, integercol, stringCol )
SELECT  column1, column2, 16, 'add text value'
FROM    Backup.dbo.table1
```

You can add a where clause and specific columns accordingly.

The column count on the select has to match the insert.